# Serving GZipped MIDI content from Apache has trouble playing in quicktime on browser. Workaround?

Tags: apache, gzip, quicktime, midi

I need to serve large MIDI files over Apache that are precompressed to a .mid.gz format and I've finally managed to get all the content-type and content negotiation working to the point that I have a compressed MIDI delivered with the right content-type and encoding. The final hurdle I'm running into is that when I load the file in the browser and try to play it in QuickTime, Quicktime shows me a Question mark icon indicating that it can't play the file.

I googled around and found this:

"Media files are sent with "Transfer encoding: chunked" set in the header and no "Content length" entry in the headers. This is because Apache can't work out how large the files are once they have been compressed, so it send them chunked. Various players can't handle chunked data so they play the first chunk or few chunks, assuming that to be the entire file."

http://www.beetlebrow.co.uk/what-do-you-need/help-and-documentation/unix-tricks-and-information/apache-gzip-compression-and-binary-files

1) I dont have chunked Transfer encoding in my header. And I do have a content-length. So why does this still not work?

Here's my header

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:646
Content-Location:compressed.mid.gz
Content-Type:audio/midi
Date:Sat, 12 Mar 2011 01:36:39 GMT
ETag:"23b8d-286-49e3e12c899e7;49e3f0864a38f"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Last-Modified:Sat, 12 Mar 2011 00:22:27 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
TCN:choice
Vary:negotiate
```

2) If the above point still holds even with the right headers, is there a workaround for this problem?

As a reference, here's a link to my compressed MIDI file:
http://174.129.57.199/compressed.mid

Comment: I am trying to further understand this problem... Why are you zipping files up ahead of time?  Are you not using mod_deflate?  If you do this correctly, only clients that support the compressed formats (as specified in the `Accept-Encoding` request header) will get the compressed format.  Then it won't matter at all.  Clients that support it will get the zipped version.  Those that don't, won't.  Also, when I connect to your server for that example MIDI file, I don't get the compressed version, even though my Accept-Encoding allows it.  I get 87,594 bytes.

Comment: Im zipping files ahead of time for disk space reasons. I will have a 150 copies of each of these 85K MIDI files per user upload which adds up to a lot. Since they are all entirely repititive content, they compress reaaaally well. Also I had played around a bit with the server config. If you clear the browser cache and hit the link again, you'll get the compressed version. 
Also, for the uncompressed version of the same file, hit this link: http://174.129.57.199/uncompressed.mid